# Using mciSendCommand to capture video frame

Tags: c#, .net, screenshot, video-processing

Using VB.Net is it possible to capture a frame from a video and save it to an image file by using mciSendCommand? (as that is what is being used to play the video)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the [MCI_CAPTURE command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743370%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I have actually been looking at that all day and I can't figure out how to use it. I tried running this `capture videoalias as d:\test.jpg at 0 0 100 100` but it just gives an error saying the command isn't supported by the driver?

Comment: Erm, are you actually using mciSendString?  MCI is too primitive to support a jpeg format.  You may need to pause the playback.